# Print a padded binary word in Racket

Tags: racket

I want to print a padded to 32 bits word in binary in Racket.  I know about `printf` and "~b", but I want it padded to be 32 bits long each time.  How do I do this?

Example

```
(printf "~b" 42) 
=> 101010
Want: 00000000000000000000000000101010
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a concise way to do it with Racket 5.3.1 and above:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.3.2.3.
-> (require racket/format)
-> (~r 42 #:base 2 #:min-width 32 #:pad-string "0")
"00000000000000000000000000101010"
```

See [racket/format](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=%7Er#%28mod-path._racket/format%29) for more details.

In older Racket versions, you can do this:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.3.
-> (require srfi/13)
-> (string-pad (number->string 42 2) 32 #\0)
"00000000000000000000000000101010"
```

Comment: It'd still be nice to have printf-style format strings so you can just say `(sprintf "%032b" 42)`, since that is a lot more concise. ;-) DSLs for the win; this is why we use regular expressions, for example.

Comment: Oh darn, my school only has v5.3.  That's not going to work...  Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

Well here's a simple, inefficient way to do it:

```
(define (pad-left length padding the-str)
  (if (> length (string-length the-str))
      (pad-left length padding (string-append padding the-str))
      the-str))

(write (pad-left 32 "0" (format "~b" 42)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I forced together a solution:

```
(define (print-word x)
  (if  (not (<= -2147483648 x 4294967295))
    (error 'print-word "ERROR This number is bigger than a word ~a" x)
    (let* ([positive-x (if (< x 0) (+ #x100000000 x)
                         x)]
           [str (number->string positive-x 2)]
           [padded-str (string-append 
                         (make-string (- 32 (string-length str)) #\0)
                         str)])
      (build-string 39 
        (λ(i) (cond [(= (remainder (+ 1 i) 5) 0) #\space]
                    [else (string-ref padded-str (- i (quotient i 5)))]))))))
```

This actually return the string with spaces between every 4 digits, as it was actually rather hard to read the other way.